# node-mysql connection error for 2nd request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

When I run my server.js which is like

```
...
var app = require('express')(), mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlConn = mysql.createConnection(connParam);
var controllers = {mysql: require('./controller/mysql.js')(app, mysqlConn, null)};
...
```

and the controller/mysql.js

```
...
module.exports = function (app, conn, data) {
...
app.get('/mysql', mysqlController);
function mysqlController (req, res, next) {
  console.log('reached mysqlController');
  conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('mysql connection established');
    }
    else {
      console.log('mysql connection ERROR');
    }
  });
  conn.query('select * from users', function (err, sqlRes) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('\tdb query success from conn');
      app.render('mysql/index.jade', {title: 'App | MySql:index', result: sqlRes},
      function (err, html) {
        console.log('\trendering mysql/index');
        res.send(html);
        conn.end(function (err) {
          console.log('mysql connection closed');
        });
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log('\tError processing query from db');
      res.send("ERROR 505");
    }
  });
}
```

For the 1st request I get the results as expected but the second time, it's not connecting...

```
:~/workspace/noder$ node server.js
Server listening to port: 8080
reached mysqlController
mysql connection established
    db query success from conn
    rendering mysql/index
mysql connection closed
reached mysqlController
mysql connection ERROR
    Error processing query from db
```

*Can someone please help me out here...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `connect()` on an already connected connection.. Try calling `connect()` in the controller/mysql function itself and not in the `app.get()`. This way `connect()` will only be called once..

Also if it doesn't fix it, in your console log of the error, print the error as well `console.log('mysql error', err);`